# Insert two double quote after encountering a specific sequence of character

Tags: java, regex, string, csv

I have been search the net for a suitable code for this requirement, but not getting any.

I have this csv file (values are not exact, one of field of the actual csv contains bmp image code)

"NAME","ROLENUMBER","SECTION","SEAT","COMMENT"
"Abhik","45","AVC","A112004DDG","HELLO3434?"
"Bob",,"AVC","FDFDF1212","IN THIS FIELD THE USER CAN MISTAKENLY ADD TWO COMMAS LIKE ,, OR ,,,"
"JOHN",,,"DFDFEDD22E","HEL;O AGAIN"

the requirement is to somehow insert a "" between every two or more ,(commas) (,, or more commas will tell me that the field value is blank except for the comment field where the user can enter that by mistake as shown in the example) so that program can understand the blank values (it is an existing logic which I dont want to change very much if Ican help it)

So after parsing the csv rows should look like 
"NAME","ROLENUMBER","SECTION","SEAT","COMMENT"
"Abhik","45","AVC","A112004DDG","HELLO3434?"
"Bob","","AVC","FDFDF1212","IN THIS FIELD THE USER CAN MISTAKENLY ADD TWO COMMAS LIKE ,, OR ,,,"
"JOHN","","","DFDFEDD22E","HEL;O AGAIN"

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your Java code here that has issue or missing your "" functionality.

Comment: Is it common for graphics data to be included in a csv file?

Comment: How to distinguish comment field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing with CSV Files, use Apache CSV libraries... they will help you get rid of all the quotes and empty values between two commas.

the problem here is, you can not use String's replace or replaceAll because these commas can be part of a value inside quotes too...

Comment: Actually I am looking for a regular expression which can take ",," and so on like ",,," or ",,,,,,,,," and replace them like below:

",,," > ","","","
",,,," > ","","","","
",,,,,," > ","","","","","","

Comment: For now I think I can assume that the chances are very less to have some typo where in the questions section the user will enter something like ",," by mistake. Thank you for your suggestion, I will check those out.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "achintya,jha,,kumar";
String newStr="";
for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); i++){
   if(s.charAt(i)==',' && s.charAt(i+1)==','){
        newStr =newStr + s.charAt(i) + "\"\"" + s.charAt(i+1);
        i=i+2;
   }
   newStr = newStr + s.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a regular expression.  Replace [any one character NOT a speech mark],[any one character NOT a speech mark] with ","?

Comment: Actually I am looking for a regular expression which can take ",," and so on like ",,," or ",,,,,,,,," and replace them like below:

",,," > ","","","
",,,," > ","","","","
",,,,,," > ","","","","","","

Comment: for some reason the carriage returns in the comment sections are removed! and the example lost its formatting....

Just want you to know that the token that I am trying to replace here contains the quotes at first and last position and within these two quotes if I have more than one comma (having more than one comma will mean that one or more field value is blank) then I will have to  insert two double quotes between two commas:
so it will be like if I have ",," (these quotes are not for denotation only, they should be included in the token) then it should get replaced with ",""," and so on.